# SP2019 Search webpart - help with searching specific list

Tags: sharepoint-server

We're using SP2019 Search webpart, the SP2019 on-prem version of PNP Modern Search.  I have the search bar on a page, and I want it to search only a specific list.  How do I do that?  Can it search a specific list or library?